# Drag and Drop items list in angularjs in MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working in MVC application and on top of it I am using Angulrjs 1.5 . I need drag and drop functionality that fulfills below requirement :

There Should be three list on page :

List A : Contains items for List A. E.g. `{ "1001", "1002", "1003", "1004" }`
List B : Contains items for List B . E.g. `{ "PopTart", "Jelly", "Chocolate" }`

Now In between there should be List C , where user can drag item from List A then item from list B, when both items from List A and List B is dragged in List C, then it should hot Controller method.

E.g. When Item from A 1001 and item from B is dragged that  makes Item C as `1001,PopTart`

Now How Can I achieve this functionality in angularJS?

Comment: You can use this directive over here. https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/blob/master/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using HTML5 drag and drop?

You can call your AngularJs function from within the ondrop event of your drop down list, you can then update the data bound to your lists accordingly

Comment: But how do I drag item from List A and List B to same container in List C

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

On the ondrop event you can call an AngularJs function that picks up which item has been moved and update your model accordingly